# Converting seconds to human readable format MM:SS Java

Tags: java, time, format, string-formatting

How can I convert a long int of seconds to the human readable format

```
MM:SS
```

Only SS should be 0 padded so

```
long = 67 -> 1:07
```

Comment: Using `/` and `%`operator.

Answer (score 15):

```
String readable = String.format("%d:%02d", s/60, s%60);
```

Comment: +1 That's much more elegant!

Comment: +1 for built in libraries and shorter simpler code.

Answer (score 2):

Use integer division by 60 to turn seconds in to whole minutes. The Modulus(%) of seconds by 60 will give the "leftover" seconds. Then use a string conversion to check for the necessity of 0 padding.

```
int minutes = (total / 60);
int seconds = (total % 60);
String secs = Integer.toString(seconds);
if (seconds < 10) {
   secs = "0" + seconds;
}
String time = minutes + ":" + secs;
```

Comment: +1 though you have unnecessary cast to `int`

Comment: no sense wasting the space to store a long. Truth be told I read the original as double, hence the cast. fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Some arithmetic :

```
long min = value / 60;
long second = value % 60 ;
String value = min + ":" + (second > 10 ? "" : "0") + second;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int duration = 90;
int min = duration/60;
int sec = duration%60;
String formattedTime = String.format("%d:%02d",min,sec);
```