# elasticsearch : add duration in “HH:mm:ss” format

Tags: elasticsearch, time

I need to store human's activity and the activity's duration in elasticsearch.
Then I need to sum the duration in Kibana.
If I store "duration" in seconds, Kibana performs the sum very well.

```
POST /activities/_doc
{ 
   "activity": "drinking cofee",
   "duration": 60
}
```

But if I store duration in “HH:mm:ss” format, Kibana thinks that it's a string and the sum is not performed.
How can I make Kibana sum durations in “HH:mm:ss” format ?

```
POST /activities/_doc
{ 
   "activity": "drinking cofee",
   "formatted_duration": "00:01:00"
}
```

I really need Kibana to show sum in “HH:mm:ss” format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not storing both? the duration in seconds for performing the sum and the formatted duration for display purposes...

Comment: IMO the correct way to store duration is in the unit you can measure (machine-readable rather than human-readable, so the machine can do any maths with it), hence, storing as an integer is a good idea, at frontend layer you would have to parse it to human readable. Maybe a `scripted field` with some simple arithmetics covered in this other question would do the job https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064759/converting-seconds-to-human-readable-format-mmss-java

Comment: agreed with @panchicore even though it's sub-optimal to have a scripted field just for that if you know the value at indexing time and could store it alongside the integer value.

Comment: If `formatted_duration` is not explicitly created as date field, it will be created dynamically as text field. I think if the field is `formatted_duration` is of type date then the sum operation would work. I'm not sure of this. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: agree with @Val, then if you don't have full control of the document poster, seems to be a good job for an ingestion pipeline.

Comment: @NishantSaini ES is not good at summing minutes from date fields